# Raspbian Python azure.storage ImportError: No module named cryptography.hazmat.primitives.keywrap

Tags: python, azure, raspbian, raspberry-pi3

Im trying to upload pictures from my RPi3 to Azure blob storage. Im using raspbian and python moduls as described below.

- setup a virtual environment 'azure' using virtualwrapper.
- Installed azure-storage like here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-python

My problem is that what ever I do I keep getting the following error

```
>>> from azure.storage import BlobService
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/pi/.virtualenvs/azure/lib/python2.7/site-packages/azure_storage-0.33.0-py2.7.egg/azure/storage/__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
from .models import (
  File "/home/pi/.virtualenvs/azure/lib/python2.7/site-packages/azure_storage-0.33.0-py2.7.egg/azure/storage/models.py", line 27, in <module>
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.keywrap import(
ImportError: No module named cryptography.hazmat.primitives.keywrap
```

I've tried `pip install cryptography` and https://pypi.python.org/pypi/azure-storage, but that didn't change anything. I keep getting the same error `ImportError: No module named cryptography.hazmat.primitives.keywrap`. I even tried just to import `azure.storage` but that throws the same error.
If anyone could shed some light on how to get `azure-storage-blob` to work on Raspbian I would be very grateful.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to stick to azure-storage 0.32.0 to avoid using cryptography if you don't need the new features of 0.33.0. There is some difficulties to get cryptography working on some system (https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-python/issues/219)